# Python multi-file opening function

Tags: python, function, loops, input

I've got this part of code, where using `input` command I made a small module where I can select desired files. Right now I need to improve that module by adding some loops? I guess. What I need is to:

1. First input asks me about data from which station, I use shortcuts to make this quick and that works.
2. After `Station` I have `Date` same I type desired date like `2015-07-19`, this also works correctly.
3. Here are some troubles. I need a function which will take all data from for example 1300 to 1500 (hhmm). Note that every file stores 5 minutes of data, so each step is every 5 minutes.

I did a variable like `Start_time` and `End_time` but I don't have any clue how to put it into my code.

Summarize:
I need a function which will open files from desired time interval one by one. Later in my code there are plots etc. but I didn't put them here to make this question more clear.

```
# Input variables
h = "Hylaty"
u = 'Hugo'
p = 'Patagonia'

Station = input('Enter a station name (Hylaty = h, Hugo = u, Patagonia = p): ')
Date = raw_input('Enter date time (yyyy-mm-dd): ')
Time = raw_input('Enter time (hh-mm): ')
Start_time = input('Enter start time: ')
End_time = input('Enter end time: ')


data = testInstance.convert(r"/Database/Python/Data/Willy/{0}/{1}/".format(Station,Date), "{0}{1}".format(Date,Time),conversionError)
end = time.time()
print("time elapsed " + str(end - start))
```

Comment: Why do you switch between `input` and `raw_input`?

Comment: Because raw_input somehow doesn't work when I'm referring to my path file when I make a "one letter" variables for my station names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Date = raw_input('Enter date time (yyyy-mm-dd): ')
Start_time_hours = int(raw_input('Enter start time (hh): ' ))
Start_time_minutes = int(raw_input('Enter start time (mm): ' ))
End_time_hours = int(raw_input('Enter end time (hh): ' ))
End_time_minutes = int(raw_input('Enter end time (mm): ' ))

Start_time_hours += (Start_time_minutes / 60)
    Start_time_minutes %= 60
    str(Start_time_minutes)
    str(Start_time_hours)
    str(End_time_minutes)
    str(End_time_hours)
    Start_time_hours_format = '{:02}'.format(Start_time_hours)
    Start_time_minutes_format = '{:02}'.format(Start_time_minutes)
    End_time_hours_format = '{:02}'.format(End_time_hours)
    End_time_minutes_format = '{:02}'.format(End_time_minutes)
    int(Start_time_minutes)
    Start_time_minutes += 5
```

This code had solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

for generating time ranges use `pandas` :

```
import pandas as pd

my_ranges = pd.date_range('2015-07-19', '2015-07-20', freq='5S')
```

This example will output:

```
In []: my_ranges
Out[]: 
DatetimeIndex(['2015-07-19 00:00:00', '2015-07-19 00:00:05',
           '2015-07-19 00:00:10', '2015-07-19 00:00:15',
           '2015-07-19 00:00:20', '2015-07-19 00:00:25',
           '2015-07-19 00:00:30', '2015-07-19 00:00:35',
           '2015-07-19 00:00:40', '2015-07-19 00:00:45',
           ...
           '2015-07-19 23:59:15', '2015-07-19 23:59:20',
           '2015-07-19 23:59:25', '2015-07-19 23:59:30',
           '2015-07-19 23:59:35', '2015-07-19 23:59:40',
           '2015-07-19 23:59:45', '2015-07-19 23:59:50',
           '2015-07-19 23:59:55', '2015-07-20 00:00:00'],
          dtype='datetime64[ns]', length=17281, freq='5S')
```

which is accesible by index and sliceable by all of pandas methods in order to extract the parallel ranges in your data set.